# Tool to add code highlighting and export to HTML

Tags: php, ruby, ide, pretty-print

I'm looking for a tool that can highlight code (Ruby, PHP, JavaScript...) like with an IDE and then export the code to html format so that when opening the html page the code looks just like with the IDE.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=highlight+code

Answer (score 3):

You [can do this](http://www.latouche.info/admin/tips/vim/vim2html.html) with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) at least, with this command:

```
:TOhtml
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8557573/367456

Answer (score 3):

You can also use code2html ([project page](http://www.palfrader.org/code2html/)) to color source code.

```
code2html file.c > code.html
```

Comment: Note on code2html: The "official" version generates HTML with `<FONT>`-tags that are deprecated now. I use my own version which generates CSS, instead. This patched CSS-enabled version can be downloaded on my website: http://www.field-theory.org/software/index.html#code2html

Comment: + a wrapper to it : http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.fi/2012/07/code2html-sh-wrapper-for-create-folder.html

Answer (score 2):

Emacs supports exporting code to html using http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el.cgi

Answer (score 1):

To be independent of editors, you can simply use the ruby [syntax](http://syntax.rubyforge.org/) gem. Here is an excerpt of the user guide, which shows the feature you are looking for:

```
require 'syntax/convertors/html'

convertor = Syntax::Convertors::HTML.for_syntax "ruby"
html = convertor.convert( File.read( "program.rb" ) )

puts html
```

Answer (score 1):

highlight_file would be fast, although PHP only solution.

```
<?php highlight_file("somefile.php"); // basic usage
highlight_file(__FILE__);
$out = highlight_file("file.php") // string variable, can be written to file etc.
?>
```

Other than that - have you tried [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/index.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Textmate can do it too. See "Create HTML From Document" in the TextMate bundle.