# :hardcopy a file in vim with full colorscheme

Tags: vim, macvim

I'd like to print some files I edited in MacVIM using full color, ***including the dark background.***

Of course I won't send it to printer, I just want to save it in PDF.

:hardcopy removes the background and applies an ugly scheme.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from :help :hardcopy

> The current highlighting colors are used in the printout, with the following
>   considerations:
>
> 1) The normal background is always rendered as white (i.e. blank paper).
>
> 2) White text or the default foreground is rendered as black, so that it shows up!
>
> 3) If 'background' is "dark", then the colours are darkened to compensate for
>      the fact that otherwise they would be too bright to show up clearly on
>      white paper.

So it would appear the answer is, no you can't from :hardcopy.

It also gives this note:

> Note: If you have problems printing with :hardcopy, an alternative is to use
>   :TOhtml and print the resulting html file from a browser.

If that's an option, that's going to be the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Rather use `:TOhtml` (this is a plugin that is usually included in the default Vim runtimes): type Q to enter Ex mode, and then:

```
let html_number_lines=1
let html_no_pre=0
TOhtml
w
visual
```

Comment: Precisely my point. Off-topic: I've never 'grasped' the advantage of going into Ex mode for things like this. Can you say what the advantage is over just doing several `:commands` in sequence?

Comment: @sehe: lesser keystrokes on the colon key. if you change `wa` to `wqa` in my example, then the account balance is positive on the user side. If you need to go back to normal mode (`:vi\%[sual]`) then I agree it is less useful.

Comment: `wa` is bad advice. That writes *all* modified open buffers which the OP may not want. That should be just `w`.

Comment: @adscriven: you're right. I assumed that only the source and the HTML buffers were opened.

Comment: Works fine on Linux/NeoVim too.